# Is it ok having two different accounts in SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, privacy, multiple-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the SO policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910400/problem-with-for-xml-explicit-clause-in-sql-server-2005/2910606#2910606

**EDIT:**
hmm...So what's the right answer? You can have multiple accounts if you don't up vote yourself?

Comment: It looks like they've been merged, both the asker and the answerer have the same user id now.

Comment: So it's not allowed. It's great:)

Comment: As long as you don't use them for sock puppetry it's tolerated, but frowned upon. If they're brought to the attention of the team they tend to be merged.

Comment: you may accept Kop answer, I tend to agree with him actually. but your account will get merge, when someone raise a question to merge, like the user in your question.

Comment: @S.Mark, let other users to decide. Which will have more votes, that will be accepted:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you can have as many accounts as you want for any reason (asking embarrassing questions, wanting to post answers/questions anonymously, wanting a fresh start, etc) as long as you don't upvote yourself.

Comment: In other words: Alts are OK, Sock Puppets are not.

Answer (score 4):

Both are unregistered accounts, so may be he just lost his browser cookies or used different browser / computer and ended up creating new account.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one case where one user has multiple accounts (three I think), but it cause(s|d) no problems.

[Oscar Reyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20654/oscar-reyes) used to have 3 accounts, but now they have been merged into one.  He had over 10k rep on at least 2 of them.