# How is it possible that someone has two accounts with the same name?

Tags: support, user-accounts, duplicate-user

How is it possible that someone has two accounts with the same name?

CHECK LINKS:

1- [eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552883/eran)

2- [eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553388/eran)

Comment: This should go on stackoverflow meta right ?

Comment: While [Jesus Ramos' answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74996/how-is-it-possible-that-someone-has-two-accounts-with-the-same-name/74997#74997) is correct to explain your scenario, just as some background it should be noted that display names have no restriction to be unique anyway. Two different users accounts, regardless of who owns them, can share the same display name - see how many [users on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users) are named "Will".

Comment: @Grace I don't think it is; these unregistered users *do* technically have an account, they just don't have an OpenID to log in to it. You should post your comment as an answer, probably

Comment: @Michael I guess I did kinda brain skip on that one on parse. The below answer is correct that they're unregistered accounts, which explains the oft scenario which leads to two accounts by the same person with matching names. It is kinda missing that "explanation" step... To make up for the quick draw I pulled on you Tuesday, feel free to take the reigns of the answer. ♪

Answer (score 4):

Names are not unique.  I had account with my openid and I accidentally created another account with google and started over with the same name.

Comment: If you still have two accounts you can have a mod [merge them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is [actually quite common (scroll down)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70362/multiple-accounts-sharing-an-email-address). This is because SO lets people have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, they could be merged as they matched on a number of fields.

But in general, it's possible to have a lot of users named "James", we don't enforce uniqueness of display names by choice.

Answer (score 0):

They are unregistered users so they don't technically have an account, if this is an issue it should be on meta. So I believe you're posting in the wrong section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is probably more than one person in the world named "eran", but the [pictures indicate that the accounts have the same email address](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/453167#453167) and are probably therefore the same person.

As per [ChrisF's suggestion](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/453183#453183), I have flagged the question asked by this user to inform the mods of this.