# Using multiple accounts (ethically)

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am a sockpuppet, may I exist if I have a real purpose?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/i-am-a-sockpuppet-may-i-exist-if-i-have-a-real-purpose)

I'm considering setting up a second account for ethical uses.

Specifically, as I'm here under my real name (used for my normal activities), I'll be at a bit of a disadvantage when it comes to discussing things where I need to hide who I work for.

Obvious examples would be any security related issues, or discussing project management issues.

Are there mechanisms (or policies) in place that would raise red-flags with me doing this? I have no interest in voting for myself, or 'gaming' the system, but I do have a responsibility to protect the confidentiality of others.

All I'm really concerned about is account suspension/deletion, or cookie issues, as I'll still use the same set of machines, as well as making sure I'm not breaking the rules.

Comment: See the question I linked as a duplicate - so long as you don't abuse the voting system, you're pretty much fine. Obviously use separate browsers, OpenIDs and emails so you don't confuse the authentication system. And see also: [Why are people allowed to have multiple user accounts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/why-are-people-allowed-to-have-multiple-user-accounts) BTW: if you *really* want to stay anonymous, there's always the "post anonymously from a library computer" route...

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not sure it is really a duplicate - I was after more of a policy statement; you yourself commented on the other thread "I haven't been banned for it yet. And only a small handful of my accounts have been unceremoniously deleted. So I say, go for it! " - it's the unceremonous deletion that I'm concerned about. I think the specific client confidentiality/security focus of this post mean it should be a topic of it's own

Comment: @Phil Unless you trip the "suspicious voting patterns" alarm by upvoting posts made with your other account, nobody will even notice that you have two accounts. With some people, the writing style might give them away, but you make coherent, well-written posts, so nobody will think twice about it.

Comment: @Anna Cool. That's what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Phil: I'll admit, that answer was perhaps a bit less helpful than it could have been... I've added a few of the points Anna makes here.

Comment: Note, if it becomes known that the account is a sock, it will probably get merged and you may get a suspension.  Merging socks is a routine task that mods do, so it is almost second nature to not think about doing it.  The suspension usually comes into play if the sock has upvoted/accepted many of the controlling account's questions/answers.  As long as the two accounts do NOT interact in any way (including you commenting from one account on something asked/answered by the other--its a common way socks are found) you shouldn't have to worry.  Best practice:  Go incognito on the sock.