# Explicit support for  multiple accounts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, multiple-accounts

I'd like to see a feature supporting multiple accounts. By all means, feel free to make this low priority.

**Motivation**

As discussed at [Using multiple accounts (ethically)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90045/using-multiple-accounts-ethically), there are occasions where it's legitimate to have multiple IDs, to avoid attaching a real name to discussions on client security or project management issues.

It seems that there's quite a few technical obstacles to overcome to avoid merging, which could be bad - e.g. if I'm discussing a security flaw related to a client project, having all my posts from my pseudonym end up attached to my real name would be very bad.

**Implementation**

**V1:** As long as the link between accounts is only visible to a very restricted group, I'd be happy with explicitly linking (it means any abuse for self-voting is easy to detect, and that self-voting on unlinked accounts could be more harshly dealt with). The only effect of the link would be to prevent merges; rep etc. would remain independent.

**V2:** Less ideal, but workable for me, would be an option to tag a post (Q or A) as 'private' so that the real ID wasn't visible to anyone other than the chosen few.

---

By *very restricted group* or *the chosen few* I'm referring to [the SO team](https://stackexchange.com/about/team), rather than community mods. This is both an exercise in due diligence, and a recognition that while a mod is generally a responsible member of the SO community, there are no guarantees that they *all* are; in much the same way, voting for a politician doesn't mean I'd share my clients with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As discussed at Using multiple accounts (ethically), there are occasions where it's legitimate to have multiple IDs, to avoid attaching a real name to discussions on client security or project management issues.

You can already accomplish this by using incognito / anonymous / inprivate mode in your browser.

Remember that we allow completely anonymous internet users to ask and answer questions at will.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that community mods can perform user merges, I think they at least should be able to see why they can't.

I don't think there are that many obstacles to overcome. There is just one: don't vote on posts made by your other account.

It's also possible that you'll be signed in as your real-name account when you go to comment on something on the post made by the other account... but your system wouldn't prevent that either.

(Edit from comments:  If you're really worried, flag one of your posts and ask a mod to annotate your account with the name of your other account to hopefully prevent future merging. It won't save you if the mods see activity that'd normally lead to a merge, but might help under normal circumstances.)

Comment: I guess a note for mods saying 'these accounts are linked' would be the way to handle that, it was the comment 'Merging socks is a routine task that mods do, so it is almost second nature to not think about doing it.' from _Will don't give a_ that makes me nervous (on linked post)

Comment: @Phil The rest of his comment says *"As long as the two accounts do NOT interact in any way (including you commenting from one account on something asked/answered by the other--its a common way socks are found) you shouldn't have to worry. Best practice: Go incognito on the sock."* which is exactly my point. Don't introduce any interaction between the accounts. Don't give the mods a reason to go look at your IPs. If you're *really* worried, flag one of your posts and ask a mod to annotate your account with the name of your other account to hopefully prevent future merging.

Comment: @Phil That note could help under normal circumstances, but mods will ignore it if there is interaction between your accounts that'd normally lead to a merge and suspension.

Comment: Ah, didn't know there were mod-private notes; that might work.