# Can I have two independent accounts without fearing merging?

Tags: support, policy, multiple-accounts

I'd like an account that isn't associated to my real name, but I really don't want to bother using different connections for the accounts. Of course I wouldn't let those two accounts communicate, e.g. through voting. It would still be obvious that I owned both accounts to a moderator who investigated them.

Can I have such a setup without fearing merging from an overzealous moderator?

If someone decided to wrongfully merge those accounts, would there be a way to dissociate the merged questions from my original account?

Comment: If you keep your two accounts completely separate, and never upvote/comment/answer in the same question, you shouldn't have to worry.  Of course, if you screw up and get merged, TS.

Comment: @Won't: Or if someone else screws up and I get merged.

Comment: @Tim: Nope.  Since having multiple accounts isn't generally allowed and there is no guarantee you *won't* be merged, you can't claim that your accounts got merged because someone else "screwed up."  You have no reasonable expectation, to steal a legal term, that your accounts won't get merged.

Comment: @Won't: Since you answer my question, maybe that should be an answer?  (I was under the impression that it [was allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts/35607#35607), though.)

Comment: @Tim: I think Chris covers this fine.  Think of the ability to have multiple accounts not as a bug but as a feature.  It isn't supported directly, can be considered a failure in the system, but is left in a gray area.  There is no official support for allowing individuals to run multiple accounts.  You can do this, yes, but more because it is nearly impossible to enforce one person = one account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit support for  multiple accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90281/explicit-support-for-multiple-accounts)

Answer (score 6):

To answer the last part of your question:

A merge (of anything, not just a user) is a one way operation. Once it's done it can't be undone.

Given that most second accounts are either created by accident by unregistered users or deliberately by people wanting to game the system the natural reaction of moderators on finding them is to want to merge.

Therefore, as there's always the possibility that **if** you did create a second account it would be merged with your main account, you would need to think long and hard before posting.

You could post as an unregistered users using incognito mode/private browsing. You'd have to keep separate bookmarks of your questions and be careful with your cookies. However, this account may still be merged.

So to answer your main question:

While you can have two independent accounts there will **always** be the risk that an "overzealous" moderator could merge them. To [quote Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts/35607#35607)

> what legitimate reason would you need for multiple accounts?

and this would *never* be a "wrongful" merge.

Comment: So basically, I'd have to game the system (proxies, tunnels) to avoid getting merged for gaming the system? =/

Comment: Isn't there a precedent of people having multiple accounts peacefully co-existing so long as there was ***no interaction*** between the accounts? In other words, so long as *account_A* did not vote on, answer, or comment on anything by *account_B*, and vice versa, that it would be okay?

Comment: [This answer from Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts/35607#35607) is germane to this.

Comment: @Al Everett - yes, but I was addressing the point about merging being non-recoverable and that there will always be a risk of merging.

Answer (score 3):

You can, provided the two accounts have *nothing* in common.

The IP address match is not really an issue, it's the emails or openids matching that will trip you up -- and intentionally, as ChrisF points out because 99% of the time when this happens it's users who accidentally do it.