# Chat shouldn't highlight commas that come after mentions if they are not part of the user's name

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

[image: screenshot]

The comma should not be highlighted in green, as it's not part of my name.

<sub>(daknøk is my other account.)</sub>

Comment: Um.. why do you have two accounts?

Comment: @Barry We all have a separate account for each SE site. The names can be changed individually. (Hopefully nobody here has just one account ;v) )

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I know how accounts work across sites but in this case the OP has another totally separate account on the same site.

Comment: relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/why-are-people-allowed-to-have-multiple-user-accounts and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts

Comment: Dude, how are you so calm about this?  The comma... being highlighted.. Oh, the huge manatee!

Comment: @Barry I wanted to start over. Don't worry, I'll never vote on my own posts.

Comment: @WTP'--: Fair enough. Although you should be aware that your accounts may well be merged together. Although no [official policy is in place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts) (as far as I am aware.) I guess the "proper" way of doing this would be to [request your account be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account) :)

Comment: @Won't: Some people are too laid back. This question needs a bounty on it. It is an outrage this has gone on for so long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed as part of the recent [@reply improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139959/115866). To be precise, it was first fixed [too well](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5205/pinged-usernames-are-not-highlighted-when-followed-by-a-comma), but now it's fixed the right amount.