# How to figure out the user with multiple accounts in SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, multiple-accounts

Considering the post (and answer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044872/run-an-anderson-darling-normality-test-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998313/remove-certain-rows-and-columns-without-shifting-the-rows-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999054/use-automator-to-convert-excel-file-format/17999098#17999098) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035278/modify-code-to-prevent-undirected-edges-in-bayesian-networks), I suspect (but not sure) that, user2640560, user2626657, and user2648898 are the same person. Is there any mechanism in SO to verify that? Also, is it okay to have multiple account in SO?

Comment: Related: [Multiple accounts and “cross-pollination” detection?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191025/multiple-accounts-and-cross-pollination-detection)

Comment: @Mat, OP's talking about the answerer and the asker for those two questions being the same user.

Comment: @ Old Checkmark: Yes, that's my concern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no way that you (as a normal user) can verify this other than by asking the person. And they could always lie to you.

Moderators, however, have tools at their disposal to investigate this. You can solicit their attention and ask them to do so by [raising a flag on one of the suspected user's posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review). Select the "other" option and write some text explaining what you think is wrong. It would be helpful to provide a link to the other profile, as well.

But it is not strictly forbidden to have multiple accounts. The only thing that you cannot do is have multiple accounts that *interact* with one another in order to game the system (e.g., vote for each others posts, accept each others answers, etc.) Since that is what you suspect to be happening here, it would be appropriate to ask a moderator to take a look.

Comment: You beat my answer by a few seconds - but FYI - the OP of this post doesn't have the rep to flag

Comment: @psubsee Really? There's a minimum reputation to flag using the "other" option?

Comment: let me double check - been a while since I've been there myself, but I thought there was

Comment: Yup - 15 rep -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's just a baseline "have you participated at all" threshold. No wonder I forgot.

Comment: that makes sense!

Comment: @user You should ask some questions or post some answers so that you can get upvotes!

Answer (score 10):

Saw the flags on this. Yes, there were shenanigans here (even beyond the above-linked questions), and things should be cleaned up now.

This was not the first time for this person, so they've been given a short vacation from the site. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Glad that it worked out!Thanks.