# Re-posting of other answers and accepting those as answers

Tags: discussion, multiple-accounts

This is continuation of the post I posted [earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191890/how-to-figure-out-the-user-with-multiple-accounts-in-so).

It's surprising that the user ([user2671112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2671112/user2671112)) who is member for 1 hour automatically get 100 reputations and donates that as bounty to another user ([user2651613](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2651613/user2651613)). It turns out that all of the answers by the former are accepted by the later and hence 100 reputations. A worst part is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092567/automatically-replace-names-in-data-frame/18165667#18165667) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007554/keep-columns-based-on-column-names/18165644#18165644) where the user2671112 copies the answer of @agstudy and @Hong Ooi and then that are accepted by OP (user2651613). Notice that there is also another answer by the another user [user2640560](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2651230/user2651230), which happens to repeat the process of user2671112. I reported in the earlier post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191890/how-to-figure-out-the-user-with-multiple-accounts-in-so) about the user2640560. This user is also re-posting the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983768/convert-all-values-in-a-data-frame-to-factors/18163809#18163809) for the question by the [user2626657](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2626657/user2626657), that was suspended earlier.

Comment: No need to put that here. Just flag one of the posts a explain the matter to a moderator.

Comment: @juergend: As mentioned in the linked question, they don't have enough reputation to flag.

Comment: That should be http://loyalkng.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/flamethrower.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've flagged a post for moderator attention. This is a clear case of sockpuppetry to game the system.

Comment: Man, this guy again? Most of this mess should be cleaned up now, but I imagine they'll try this again. Something more severe might be required now.

Comment: @BradLarson Cheaters and people with other malicious intents never give up. The blog I contribute to is being **regularily** spammed by **the very same person,** he creates a new sockpuppet Facebook/Wordpress account like once a week.

Comment: @H2CO3: Hrm, they all give up *eventually*. I know of a few accounts that after endless attempts did give up or found something else to occupy them. Keep whacking them, they will eventually get bored enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, our friendly PHP/Python troll doesn't seem like he's getting bored anytime soon. We're well over 100 deleted accounts for him since the start of the year.

Comment: @BradLarson who is this person specifically. Like what is the first question regarding him here?

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Context: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181760/when-enough-is-enough

Comment: @BradLarson what's allowing him to evade the IP ban?

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Don't know how much detail I can get into, but he's been way more creative about how he accesses the site than any other troll I've encountered.

Comment: But, @Brad, getting 100 rep by getting all their answers accepted by the same user (and then that being returned using a bounty) surely could trigger some automated alarm? (I know, an automated flag still needs you to take care of that, and I know you cannot reveal too much. And today's abuse was reported quite quickly, maybe before any scripts did run.)

Comment: He mentioned in comments to one of his posts last week that he has something he called a "Cloud IP" service, @Cole, so he can change his IP at will. Given the level of sophistication in his posts, he's probably using someone else's tool -- Tor, maybe?

Comment: @JoshCaswell if he is in fact using Tor, IP bans are moot and just harm the Tor out node.