# Multiple Accounts in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts, merged-questions, multiple-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)
>   [What's the SO policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts)

This might have been asked a number of times. But still, I thought It was not a big deal to have multiple accounts on Stack Overflow.

I personally have 2 accounts. I do not exactly recall why I created 2 accounts to be exact.

As I can remember, I had associated one of the accounts with my personal Gmail account and with limited access (Gmail was blocked in my previous company). I opted for a new account based on OpenID.

Now, I saw some posts, which seem to suggest, it does not go with the spirit of "SO" to have multiple accounts.

If that is the case, I would merge both the accounts, if that is possible.

Answer (score 16):

If you use one account to upvote the other, that is not allowed and when discovered a mod will merge your accounts and suspend you.

If by some chance the existence of your other account(s) is discovered, they will most likely be merged.  There is no guarantee that you can do this, and that your accounts won't be merged underneath you.  The majority of users with multiple accounts have them because they don't understand how the account system works.  Mods regularly merge accounts, therefore we don't spend time confirming you want them merged.

As for the "spirit" of SO, unless you are sockpuppeting for rep, its fine.  Just don't be surprised to find you only have one account.

Comment: Well, I have separate a stackoverflow account for work. [Keeping my personal account separate is a must](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402566/using-a-personal-stack-overflow-account-for-a-team-potentially-allows-your-emplo#:~:text=The%20following%20steps%20show%20how,added%20to%20your%20personal%20account). However, it'd be nice to log on with my personal account from time-to-time so I have access to bookmarks and history. Often I think "Ah! I read about a solution to this before... but on my personal account." Now I use two browsers to get around the issue.