# How to use multiple SE accounts with the new login system easily?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, hidden-features

There are SE sites which I want to use without being identifiable my main account. Thus, I have a secondary SE account, too.

(To prevent temptations ;-), currently there is no SE site for which I would be registered with both of them.)

Earlier it was very simple: simply I was logged in into the different SE sites with my different accounts. If I wanted to log in, I could simply choose, which of my accounts I want to use.

What I could do: I could use some browser addon (or multiple browsers) which would enable me to use different session cookies.

But I am looking for a better solution: ideally, for one which doesn't trigger your possible warning scripts, but makes this even looking legal.

Comment: No, don't downvote, using multiple stackexchange accounts are [competely allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104903/multiple-accounts-in-stack-overflow).

Comment: Nick's answer there applies to this one too; logging in is moving to one login for the whole top-level domain. If you want to use a different account for some parts of that domain, you'll have to log out, and log in with the other account. Or use separate browsers to handle the two separate accounts.