# Is possible to create another user on SO

Tags: discussion, support, multiple-accounts

I thinking about to create a new user on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) with purposes

- learning different programing language as a new user, starting there with zero reputations,
- and concurrently to use my [mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel) active for [Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing), for answering only to the wrong answered, special or interesting (for me) questions
- please is possible to set or restrict relationship betweens two users somehow, meaning against known and common issue with cross_answering and up/down voting

maybe my question could be funny, but now I want do that this clear way, sure in the case if is possible that somehow

Comment: Why start at zero reputation? I agree it's an interesting social experiment, I did the same thing once for a while just to find out whether reputation influences voting. (Result: it does.) But for serious activity - why? You're one and the same person, whether you do Java or some new language, aren't you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts

Comment: @Pekka: perhaps your zero-reputation you was subconsciously writing worse answers because it knew, deep down, that it was never going to be as good as the high-reputation you.

Comment: I have to huge reputations for small area in SO, and upto summer I'll 40k, ...... by default there are very funny questions by users with rep >10k that abuse your rep power,

Comment: What's the point of this?

Comment: @mKorbel your [last comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124606/is-possible-to-create-another-user-on-so/124607#comment334335_124606) doesn't makes much sense, can you be more clear please?

Comment: you can focus on trying to earn language specific badges if you want to have "something" to show as an achievement towards a specific language.

Comment: @UncleZeiv :-) no I don't want something, only idea how to split my person to the diff_IDs, by using regullar/correct way:-), because there are three maybe four ways how to do it another way, but in these cases would be my question to much contraproductive

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Possible? yes. Encouraged? no.

Your reputation alone does not say "you are an expert in all things programming" - it says you know how to use the site, and have contributed. That won't change just because you start using a new language. A good question (/answer) is a good question (/answer) regardless of whether the person asking it has 1 rep or 10,000. Likewise a bad question (/answer).

So just concentrate on writing sensible questions (/answers).

The only thing this causes is confusion and a temptation (ever so slight) to click that "upvote" button occasionally. It also raises the issue (that we've seen many times) of people then having **twice** their normal voting power towards other users, and that... *does not go down well*.

Comment: Also worth to mention that using two accounts from the same machine might trigger automatic accounts merge - saw people complaining about it here on Meta.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd there's usually more to it than just having two accounts, but ... I know what you are saying.

Comment: @Marc Gravell agreed rep talking in most cases about nothing, hehehe very interesting your `Encouraged? no`, nice described answer for meta SO, but too wide for my question, results could by to delete current user or I'll ask for lock by admin,

Comment: @mKorbel there is no such thing as a "lock" at the user level, unless you mean a suspension. I'm still very unclear on what reason any of this is necessary for? What doesn't work if you just use your existing account? What is the actual *problem* here?

Comment: @Marc Gravell  there isn't any problem, nor shadowed something, in this case I'll never asked this question, I think I'm learning Java with Swing very well, and after summer (this year) I want to learning something different, my two cents that with my rep. power I'll get very good answers f.e on VB / VBA /VBE tags too(most downvoted from tags), but learning nothing, simple my idea is starting with zero, sure this rep could be interesting for potential employer only , but this is in the heavens now :-)