# Answer edited, rolled back, then same edit added to question (by someone else)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, user-accounts, users

I don't know how to title the question. The current one is the best I have come up with.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120865/how-does-the-size-of-a-pointer-change-when-it-is-pointing-at-a-single-character/14120906#14120906) is the thread in question. Please see the edit history of

- the question
- my (User Krishnabhadra) answer

And take a note of the timings. This is a what happened.

1. I replied to the original question asked by OP.
2. Sometime later a new user (say user X) edited my answer, and added an example code, to demonstrate the question (not my answer). **That is NOW my answer contains, what the question should originally had, bit of code**. The edit even contains a statement

   > Sorry should have put the an example first
3. Then this user X edits my answer again, removed the code he added, and returned it to its original form.
4. Then OP edited the question, added the same edit to the question. The new edit in the question exactly corresponds to the edit my answer had a few seconds back. Remember OP and User X ae 2 different people (supposedly).
5. During the time my answer was edited, I asked a comment about it, and User X replied by saying the edit was erroneous.

Well that is a short timeline of edits and confusion. I was really confused when I saw that my answer is edited with some coded that made no sense to me in the context.

I am not sure whether this is the correct place to put this, since this is not a question. Close it if you think it is off topic here. But I think User X and OP is a single person.

Comment: The OP could have seen the edit and copied it from the history, nothing *necessarily* suspicious there.

Comment: @Martin Pieters Yes OP could have done that.. But there is no need for User X to put **Sorry should have put the an example first** in the edit in my answer.. BTW I only posted this since I suspected some foul play behind.. Close this if you think it is unwarranted..

Comment: Looking into this now.

Comment: We'll take a look, needless to say, we can't give you much insight as to whether or not they are.  But let's just say that we received the message.

Comment: Honestly, it just looks like someone with edit privileges rolled back and edit that shouldn't have been made.  Nothing to see here.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas,Tim thanks.. I don't have anything about the guy.. After some [research](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts) I now know it is okay to have multiple account in stackoverflow as long as it is not used for foul play.. So no problem for me, other than wondering what is a legitimate use of having multiple account.

Comment: I think that your assumption that this might be from the same account is inherently flawed.

Comment: Ok.. I am leaving it at that.. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are the same person there is no problem - lots of people keep multiple SO identities (I have another account myself). Where it does become a problem is when they use them as sock puppet accounts to up vote questions/answers posted under the other accounts.

In any case all that happened here is the OP posted the example on your answer rather than his question, and another account was used to correct that. Even if they are the same person, there is no problem. There have been a number of times where I have copied code out of comments and/or answers and edited it into the question - it happens.

Comment: Ok.. then I don't have any problem either..

Answer (score 4):

OK, so you seem to think that the two users (Petesh and the OP) are the same. For one, it looks pretty innocent--the OP edited an example into your post, and Petesh noticed it, reverting it. The OP then added it to his own post.

Anyway, having multiple accounts is OK as long as you don't vote for each other. I've let the relevant moderators know about these two accounts, though, they will deal with it if there's anything suspicious.

Comment: He suspects the OP has a sock puppet, and that that sock puppet edited his answer by accident. At least that's what I understand from the OP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes that is it..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: K, I forwarded it to the mods. They're looking into it.