# Two users, one for SO, one for other sites

Tags: support

I have two users on SE. Both of them are registered in SO, and one of them is tied to other SE communities accounts like Arqade, ELL, etc. How can I sign into SO with one account while signing into other communities with another account? When I log out from one account from one community it seems I'm log out from all communities.

Comment: I'm not sure how possible this is after the Login changes.

Comment: If you don't wish to merge, the only really feasible answers are "You can't" or "Use two separate browsers." Actually, using two _profiles_ in a browser, if you're using a browser that can do that, should make this possible for you. It's not _great_ and it's a workaround, but it's possible.

Comment: @Kendra: A quick-and-dirty solution is to log into one of the accounts normally, and into the other one in Incognito / Private Browsing mode. (And yes, Incognito mode *is* basically a second browser profile, just with a convenient menu shortcut to access it and some extra privacy features enabled by default.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I had completely forgotten about private mode... Definitely a quick-and-dirty solution, but handy if you only need this once or twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keen's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276048/266735) is the best way to go if you didn't create the two accounts to specifically have two accounts.

If you *did* want two accounts, for instance to keep your work and personal usages of the sites separate, then merging your accounts isn't what you're looking for. So long as there is zero interaction between your accounts (for instance, voting) and you're not using the accounts to do things you shouldn't be able to (for instance, voting on a post twice) then there really isn't a rule against two accounts. [It's *discouraged* but not against the rules.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/266735)

Keeping that in mind, you cannot accomplish this with on-site means unless you want your accounts merged. There are a couple options for *off-site* means, however:

1. Use two different browsers

   This method is probably one of the easiest. If you sign into one account on Chrome and one account on Firefox, for instance, then you never have to sign out of either account to use the other. It's not perfect, but it works well.
2. Use two different browser profiles

   Very similar to the above approach, but in one single browser. Some browsers, for instance Chrome (and I believe Firefox), allow you to have the same browser running with different *sessions* with them. The cookies and all are different between the two sessions. This would give you the same effect as running two browsers, but with only one browser to work with.

   This would *also* be achievable with Incognito/Private browsing, as mentioned in the comments. Using Incognito/Private browsing might be preferable if you only log into the one account occasionally but the other far more often. Log into the account you use most on a regular session of your browser, and the other in Incognito mode.
3. Use two different devices

   This method is, of course, not available easily to everyone. Not everyone has two computers or a computer and a smart phone, or a computer at all. But if you do, you *could* always set up one device with a certain account, and put the other account on a different device. It's not nearly as handy as the other two methods, in my opinion, and it does require having two devices you can access Stack Exchange on, but it is an option.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of every page on Stack Overflow, there's a 'contact us' link. Click it. In the 'What can we help you with?' dropdown, select the merge profiles option. Then provide links to both profiles, and submit your request.

A Stack Overflow employee will then be able to help clean up your extra account. Once this is done, signing in on one site should then sign you in across the network.