# Change ownership of a post

Tags: support, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

There are some questions which were written with my (mainly used) pseudonymous account, but contain some identifiable information, so it would be great if this account could take ownership.

As [it is OK to have multiple accounts,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/289870) and both merging accounts and
dissociating yourself from a question is possible, too, would the
Stack Exchange team be willing to **change the ownership of these
posts**?

Comment: Yes, just use the 'contact us' link which you can find at the bottom of each page. 'I need to merge user profiles' is the option you need.

Comment: @Glorfindel:Thank you for the reply. This question is about keeping them separate and just moving some posts ownership to this account.

Comment: What for? Why spend their time on something like that?? (anyway, not a dupe indeed, reopened.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: because otherwise I'd ask for dissociation, which probably takes just as much time.

Comment: Pretty sure they have built in tools for disassociation. Pretty sure they don't have any tools to change the post author. Of course a developer can run a direct query on the database, but like I said, I don't think that anything can justify such a thing.

Comment: @MK then just merge them and create new shadow accounts?

Comment: @Glorfindel: The main account is supposed to be the shadow account, with the ID'd one just containing a few posts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We have tools for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Community managers can *disassociate* posts, but it's more work to *move* them.  While I have, once, seen them willing to move posts, I don't think it's a service they want to provide except in very special circumstances.  As a moderator I've sometimes gotten pushback even for disassociation; it's not free.

If you don't want a post to be associated with your name, use the "contact us" form to request disassociation.  If you can make a strong case for moving, use that form to ask.

I trust that in the future you'll be careful about posting from the intended account.

Comment: Direct db access isn't necessary. There's UI for this and CMs have access to it. Whether or not we'd be willing to move posts in this case is another matter and I can't necessarily speak for that in the general case... "contact us" is the way to go here.

Comment: @AdamLear oh, thanks!  I thought direct DB access had been needed in the one case I knew about, but it was also a while ago so perhaps I misremembered.  I've edited.