# What should I do if I don't want a question to be associated with this account?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, best-practices, anonymous, post-disassociation

I have several questions that I want to ask that I don't want to be linked back to me by the people about whom I'm asking*, who might recognize my username. There are others that would require disclosing personal information that would be just fine on its own, but that I don't want to be associated with my username.

I understand that questions can be dissociated from the OP by a moderator, but as far as I can tell that is a *retroactive* measure. If I know beforehand that the question is best not associated with my account, what is the best course of action?

<sup>*These are complex situations and taking the risk of them making the connection is not the right course of action.</sup>

Comment: You could always create another account. As long as your multiple accounts don't interact with each other that's OK. I.e. don't do anything with 2 accounts that you couldn't do with one such as vote on one of your own posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a sockpuppet account and ask the question this way. See this authoritative [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/377968) on how to handle sockpuppets.

I've seen this several times, even in case of answers when they didn't want them to be associated with their account (often named something like *Throwaway...*). As long as you don't abuse it (vote for your other account's post, harass people), it's fine. After all, SE is about the *content*, not the *person*.

Comment: Note: if you create multiple accounts, [they may automatically merge them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307348/stop-automatically-merging-accounts-without-asking-the-users).

Comment: After posting the question, you should request dissociation so that in case the accounts get merged, it won't affect the post.

Comment: Worth pointing it you don’t even have to create a user to ask a question.  Can’t merge a user that doesn’t exist.